# Ruby Extract Slippery Text Columns

Tags: regex, ruby, parsing

I am needing to get some columnized-text into `ruby` arrays.  They are company names, phone numbers and websites.  I've obscured the actual data in order to focus on the parsing as opposed to the nature of the data, which I can deal with.

[here is the Gist](https://gist.github.com/daBee/5f6dc2af83dccda8a174cb72736c2e13)

As you can see, the nature of the columnar data changes, including:

- leading whitespace width changes, from 0 to ~8
- some lines are "" or **\s+{3,}**
- column width changes depending on which block it's in (see how line 31 changes from 27)

  - therefore reliance upon using widths becomes problematic
- some lines show empty entries in columns

  - empty column 1 on line 4 (example)
  - empty column 2 on line 2 (example)
  - empty column 3 on line 3 (example)

I'm wanting to get this organized into col1, col2 and col3 as arrays of entries.  I can split them later on **/\s*/** and choose the first element.

Given the obvious structure of these three columns, I'm thinking there is a pragmatic way of parsing these columns out into arrays of entries, one per line.

Does anybody have any insight into how to parse out the columns?  `Columns` -> `arrays` `col1`, `col2`, `col3` is the format which I seek.

Any advice/insight appreciated.

Comment: 1. Are “blocks” (contiguous groups of lines) separated by one or more lines that are empty or contain nothing but whitespace? 2. Can tabs be present and if so how many spaces per tab? 3. The example suggests files are small enough that memory is sufficient to “gulp” them into arrays (rather than having to read them line-by-line). Correct? 4. Are columns separated by at least N spaces? If so, what is N?

Comment: 5. Can there be empty rows within a block? If so, what is the minimum number of empty rows between blocks?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Just like the file is presented, just more lines.  Empty lines are `\n`. There are not tabs in the source text. I'm not clear on if you are asking to put tabs. The master file is 3300 lines. The Gist shows the pattern: separation is variable depending on width of company/phone/url.  As per the Gist, yes empty rows, which are `\n`.  There is no minimum.

Comment: @CarySwoveland 1-27, 31-59, 63-97, 101-127 are blocks.  The source is manually roughly edited to take out large irrelevant blocks.  This is not precise.

Comment: If the example in my answer covers all the bases you may want to use it in your question in place of the one you linked. Examples should always be as short as possible while covering relevant requirements. When giving an example you should always show the desired result (as a Ruby object). If possible, assign a variable to all inputs (e.g., `str = "..."`), so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them. Lastly, it's always best for the example data to be part of the question (as text), to facilitate cut-and-paste.

Comment: The one I linked is the original, and yours is much smaller.  Your data might not cover what my requirements are, without me spending a week going over my original data.  That's why it's posted so long.  Next time I will include the full text in the post.  I don't know why you wouldn't test on the original posted dataset.  Shortening it only asks for unforseen errors.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose we gulp the file into a string, using [IO::read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-read), where the string is as follows.

```
str=<<~END
aaa bb cccc     aaaaaaa      aaaa bbb
  aaaaaaaa                aaaaaaaaa
   aaaaa                   aaaaa bbbb
aaaaa bb cc    aaaaaaa


aaa bbb   aaaaaa bbb      aaaaa bbbbbb
 aaaa                   aaaaaaaaaaaa
          aaaaaaaaa
  a bb                 aaaaaaaaa
END
```

The first step is to divide the string into (two) blocks, which we can do as follows:

```
a1 = str.split(/\n{2,}/)
  #=> ["aaa bb cccc     aaaaaaa      aaaa bbb\n  aaaaaaaa                aaaaaaaaa\n   aaaaa                   aaaaa bbbb\naaaaa bb cc    aaaaaaa",
  #    "aaa bbb   aaaaaa bbb      aaaaa bbbbbb\n aaaa                   aaaaaaaaaaaa\n          aaaaaaaaa\n  a bb                 aaaaaaaaa\n"]
```

Next, convert each of the two blocks to an array of lines.

```
a2 = a1.map { |s| s.chomp.split(/\n/) }
  #=> [["aaa bb cccc     aaaaaaa      aaaa bbb",
  #     "  aaaaaaaa                aaaaaaaaa",
  #     "   aaaaa                   aaaaa bbbb",
  #     "aaaaa bb cc    aaaaaaa"],
  #    ["aaa bbb   aaaaaa bbb      aaaaa bbbbbb",
  #     " aaaa                   aaaaaaaaaaaa",
  #     "          aaaaaaaaa",
  #     "  a bb                 aaaaaaaaa"]]
```

We need to now map each each element of `a2` (a string) to an array whose "columns" correspond to the columns of the original text.

```
a3 = a2.flat_map do |group|
  indent = group.map { |line| line =~ /\S/ }.min
  mx_len = group.map(&:length).max
  break_cols = (indent..mx_len-1).each_with_object([]) do |i,cols|
    cols << i if group.all? { |line| [" ", nil].include?(line[i]) }
  end
  b1, b2 = [break_cols.first, break_cols.last]    
  group.map { |line| [line[0..b1-1], line[b1..b2-1], line[b2..-1]] }
end
  #=> [["aaa bb cccc", "     aaaaaaa  ", "    aaaa bbb"],
  #    ["  aaaaaaaa ", "              ", " aaaaaaaaa"],
  #    ["   aaaaa   ", "              ", "  aaaaa bbbb"],
  #    ["aaaaa bb cc", "    aaaaaaa", nil],
  #    ["aaa bbb", "   aaaaaa bbb  ", "    aaaaa bbbbbb"],
  #    [" aaaa  ", "               ", "  aaaaaaaaaaaa"],
  #    ["       ", "   aaaaaaaaa", nil],
  #    ["  a bb ", "               ", " aaaaaaaaa"]]
```

`line =~ /\S/` returns the index of the first element of `line` that contains a character of than a whitespace (the reserved character `\S` in regular expressions.)

See [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map).

The following intermediate values were obtained in the calculation of `a3`.

For group 1:

```
mx_len = 37
indent = 0
break_cols = [11, 12, 13, 14, 23, 24, 25]
b1 = 11
b2 = 25
```

For group 2:

```
mx_len = 38
indent = 0
break_cols = [7, 8, 9, 20, 21, 22]
b1 = 7
b2 = 22
```

All that remains is to convert `nil`'s to empty strings, strip spaces from the ends of each string and transpose the array.

```
a3.map { |col| col.map { |s| s.to_s.strip } }.transpose
  #=> [["aaa bb cccc", "aaaaaaaa", "aaaaa", "aaaaa bb cc",
  #     "aaa bbb", "aaaa", "", "a bb"],
  #    ["aaaaaaa", "", "", "aaaaaaa", "aaaaaa bbb", "",
  #     "aaaaaaaaa", ""],
  #    ["aaaa bbb", "aaaaaaaaa", "aaaaa bbbb", "",
  #     "aaaaa bbbbbb", "aaaaaaaaaaaa", "", "aaaaaaaaa"]]
```

If desired, we could of course chain the above operations.

```
str.split(/\n{2,}/).
    map { |s| s.chomp.split(/\n/) }.
    flat_map do |group|
      indent = group.map { |line| line =~ /\S/ }.min
      mx_len = group.map(&:length).max
      break_cols = (indent..mx_len-1).each_with_object([]) do |i,cols|
      cols << i if group.all? { |line| [" ", nil].include?(line[i]) }
    end
    b1, b2 = [break_cols.first, break_cols.last]    
    group.map { |line| [line[0..b1-1], line[b1..b2-1], line[b2..-1]] }
  end.map { |col| col.map { |s| s.to_s.strip } }.transpose
```

Comment: So you took the length approach as I did.  I found an easier method so far...set `\s{3,}` to `'•'` and go from there.  It takes all the lengths out of play.  if the new lines start with `•` then I delete that and I then split on `•` and I have my array. You put some time into this.

Comment: I considered your `\s{3,}` but thought the way I did it would be safer in case the data format were to change in future, allowing three or more spaces within columns or fewer than three spaces to define columns. It was only a few lines of code.

Comment: Right now I'm finding  `line.gsub(/\s{2,44}/,'•')` to put that delimiter on a line that starts with `^` only.  Using that `.gsub` takes away all the spacing pain.

Comment: I did try it with the data at your link but had a problem saving it to a variable (i.e., `str=<<~ <your data>; end` hung). Perhaps you could check it and report back. I'm off for walk with my canine companion. Will check back later.

Comment: I don't have the original anymore.  It was fabricated data.  But it held the structure.  That file was actually for visual purposes to show how column widths changed, which was what I was hung up on.  Did you see how I approached it since then?  I just got it to work now.

Answer (score 0):

As Cary has demonstrated, working with widths was painful.  That's what tripped me up.  I took a new approach at doing a `String.gsub(/\s{2,44}/,'•')` so it would preserve column widths while inserting delimiters:

```
col1, col2, col3 = [],[], []
master_data = []

lines = File.open(s, 'r+').read.split("\n")
lines.each do |line|
  next if line == "" || line.strip == ""

  nline = line.gsub(/\s{2,44}/,'•')
  nline[0] = '' if nline.start_with?('•')
  nline = nline.split('•')

  col1 << nline[0]
  col2 << nline[1]
  col3 << nline[2]
end

col1.delete_if {|i| i.nil?}
col2.delete_if {|i| i.nil?}
col3.delete_if {|i| i.nil?}

# ap col1
# puts
# ap col2
# puts
# ap col3

counter = 0
col1.each do |i|
  next if i.nil?
  if i.match?(/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/)                     # matches a phone number, perhaps a big assumption
    company = [col1[counter-1], col1[counter], col1[counter+1]]
    master_data << company
  end
  counter += 1
end

# a company is a company name, phone number, and website
# do the same for col2 and col3

ap master_data
```

Comment: Not true.  Entries with nothing in the first column will shift all items to the first column.

Comment: Ah, yes. Good catch!

Comment: Haha this has been a very tricky one.  The lateral spacing was more of an issue.

Comment: A few notes: `File.open(s, 'r+').read.split("\n")` is the same as `File.open(s).read.split("\n")`. Because `open` is not used with a block the file is not closed after it is read. Better: `File.read(s).split("\n")`. Best: `File.readlines(s, chomp:true)`. Also, `next if line == "" || line.strip == ""` is the same as `next if line.strip.empty?`.

Comment: You need to initialize `col1`, `col2` and `col3` to empty arrays. After doing so I ran your code without the lines `lines = File.open(s, 'r+').read.split("\n")` and `ap master_data`, and with `lines  = ["a", " "*25+"b", " "*50+"c"]`. (`lines[2]`, for example, contains 50 spaces followed by  `"c"`). I get `master_data #=> []`, `col1 #=> ["a", "b", ""]`, `col2 #=> ["c"]`, `col3 #=> []`. Is that intended?

Comment: For some reason the three ticks, start and finish, can't be on the same line as displayed syntax.  It was all in there from the copy, but when posted I didn't catch it.

Comment: I come from a language that uses hard comparators instead of method names.  All the same.